How to hide something in mangnified area (TikZ spy)?
I have a tikzpicture with multiple plots and a spy node that magnifies an area of the axis. How can I hide the only marks plot in the magnified area such that only the graphics plot is shown in there?
MWE
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=2.5, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    hide axis,
]
\addplot graphics [
    xmin=-1,xmax=1,
    ymin=-1,ymax=1,
] {example-image-duck};

% these markers should be hidden in the spy
\addplot [only marks, mark=x, red] coordinates {
(-0.1, 0.075)
(-0.15, 0.1)
};

\coordinate (spypoint-1) at (axis cs:-0.1,0.075);
\coordinate (magnifyglass-1) at (axis cs:0.5,0.5);
\end{axis}

\spy[white, size=1cm] on (spypoint-1) in node at (magnifyglass-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I don't think there is any easy way to do this because the spy library goes to quite elaborate lengths to ensure it captures everything and that is, more-or-less, its purpose i.e. to magnify what's there.
